# Xcode 13 standard spacing is not available anymore in interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, xib

In Xcode 13 interface builder i can't use standard spacing in "Add new constraint" menu.
It's not available neither for parent of sibling views/labels etc.

I've tested it in both xib and storyboard files.

How to use standard spacing in xcode 13? Is it a bug or i'm missing something?

[image: storyboard sibling]
[image: xib parent]

Comment: The `Standard` is usually set when you have moved/dragged/resized the `UIView` to the `Standard` spacing. I believe you will need to do some resizing to get it to show